# Preserving Field Order in Elasticsearch _source Retrieval?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, elastic-stack, opensearch

I'm working with Elasticsearch and have encountered an issue with the order of fields within nested objects when retrieving documents using _source.

```
{
  "student_id": "123",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "courses": {
    "Math": {
      "grade": "A",
      "teacher": "Mr. Smith"
    },
    "Science": {
      "grade": "B",
      "teacher": "Ms. Johnson"
    }
  }
}
```

When I retrieve this document using _source (Exclude -> student_id), the order of fields seems to change. This becomes problematic for my application logic, where the order of fields is significant.

```
{
  "courses": {
    "Science": {
      "teacher": "Ms. Johnson",
      "grade": "B"
    },
    "Math": {
      "grade": "A",
      "teacher": "Mr. Smith"
    }
  },
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that the order of fields within nested objects is preserved when retrieving documents using _source in Elasticsearch? Alternatively, are there any best practices or workarounds to handle this issue?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this challenge. Thanks!

I attempted to address the problem by adding an additional field called "OrderField" to my documents. This field stores the order of fields within the nested object. Here's an example of how I structured my document:

```
{
  "courses": {
    "Science": {
      "teacher": "Ms. Johnson",
      "grade": "B"
    },
    "Math": {
      "grade": "A",
      "teacher": "Mr. Smith"
    }
  },
  "name": "John Doe",
  "OrderField": {
    "student_id": 0,
    "name": 1,
    "courses": 2
  }
}
```

This works!, but I'm exploring alternative solutions to minimize storage overhead.

One idea I'm considering is compressing the nested object ("B" field) before storing it. By compressing the data, I hope to reduce the storage costs associated with adding additional fields for ordering purposes.

Here's a simplified example of the proposed approach:

```
{
  "student_id": "123",
  "B": "compressed_data"
}
```